# How does ESM tree-shaking / dead code elimination work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm curious how tree-shaking/dead code elimination of ESM works. I'm using Typescript for various Node.js projects and I started to export my own ESM packages (`tsc --module es2015 --target es5 --outDir dist/esm`) instead of CJS packages. Moreover, I tried to replace dependencies (like lodash) that are only available as CJS module with libraries that are available as ESM.

When I build a project, my entire TS codebase (`./src`) is transpiled to JS (`./dist`); dependencies are still taken from (`./node_modules`). No tree-shaking performed.

I guess I'd still need a bundler (like Webpack) that needs (at least) an entry point so that it can shake away everything that's not needed, so that I can reduce the package size of (e.g.) an AWS lambda? Is this something you would do?

Answer (score 5):

When you use `import` instead of `require`, the transpiler is able to build the dependency tree on compile time (that is why you cannot dynamically `import` code).

For example, if you write this:

```js
import { myfunc } from 'mylib';
```

The transpiler understands that you only need the `myfunc` function from `mylib`. If `mylib` includes other functions that are not used by `myfunc`, the transpiler can remove them from the bundle.

This is the short version. Tree-shaking is actually more complex than that. Webpack has a good article about it if you want to learn more:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Comment: You're right, but that was not really what I was asking. The Typescript compiler does not perform any tree shaking whatsoever. So it is something a bundler has to do, I guess? Is this something you would also do for your (backend) applications like for a lambda?

Comment: Yes, Typescript will just transpile from ts to js with imports. It is the role of the bundler to do the tree-shaking part.

Comment: BTW, tree-shaking a lambda will not give you much performance improvements. Tree-shaking is most useful on browsers, to avoid downloading code that is not useful. Lambdas have access to a very high bandwidth network, so tree-shaking them will just make them harder to debug.

Comment: that's what i was thinking as well. just wanted to make sure i'm on the right path.

Comment: If mylib index is involving many exports, will it still work? For instance, I have a package that mixes React components and core logic. It seems that if another package depends only on the core logic, I still end up with a React dependency.
Am I expected to avoid such big index and maybe favour having nested files, like "mylib/core", "mylib/react" for instance? Shouldn't tree shaking handle that already?