# Importing leaflet into module from cdn with typescript support

Tags: javascript, typescript, leaflet

I'm trying to import leaflet into a javascript module with typescript support but can't get it to work.

I've installed @types/leaflet and have tried to following:
`import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.8.0/leaflet.js'`
This works fine in the browser but typescript gives the following error:
`'L' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.ts(2686)`
(I call L.map() in my code)

I've also tried:
`import * as L from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.8.0/leaflet.js'`
This works fine in typescript, but gives the following error in chrome:
`Uncaught TypeError: L.map is not a function`

Anyone know how to fix this?
I don't want to use a bundler.

**Edit**
As jsejcksn suggested in the comments, importing a ES module version of leaflet and adding a path alias to typescript fixed this.
I'm now using the following import:
`import * as L from 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet-src.esm.js'`
The problem with this though, as stated on [Leaflet's Download page](https://leafletjs.com/download.html), is that this imports Leaflet's source files including unit tests, files for debugging, build scripts, etc. This doesn't seem very efficient to me.
Any other ideas?

**Edit 2**
It seems like Leaflet 1.9 will solve my problem when it will be released. This [pull request](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/8329) adds an ES module entrypoint to Leaflet meaning you can do this:
`import L from 'leaflet'`
or in our case:
`import L from 'cdn.com/link/to/leaflet/1.9/esm'`

In the mean time, jsejcksn's answer provides a good alternative so I will accept that answer.

Comment: I didn't examine the response at the CDN listed in your question, but if you have access to an actual ES module (not UMD) version of leaflet at a CDN (maybe that one is), then see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70728275/438273). If that answers your question, then we can mark this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @jsejcksn Thanks for answering. I think the version of leaflet I was trying to import was a UMD. I found a ES module version though. See edit in my question.

Comment: If the leaflet maintainers aren't publishing ES modules [optimized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63520203/438273) for production, then that's something you should [open an issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/new/choose) about (after reviewing these related ones: [ES Module not being shipped](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/6131), [Gradually migrating to TypeScript](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/7591)).

Comment: @jsejcksn I looked around a bit more in the leaflet github and it just so happens they merged a [pull request](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/8329) a couple days ago providing leaflet's global `L` as a default export. It seems it will be released with leaflet 1.9.

Comment: Thanks, I see it. It seems relevant (based on what you've shared) to mention that, in the initial message, it is stated that tree-shaking is a non-goal of the PR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Preface

I've already written an answer about how to do this with ES modules at the question [How to include modules in client side in typescript projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70728275/438273). Be sure to read through that question and answer for context here.

You said:

> I don't want to use a bundler.

and also:

> The problem with this though, as stated on [Leaflet's Download page](https://leafletjs.com/download.html), is that this imports Leaflet's source files including unit tests, files for debugging, build scripts, etc. This doesn't seem very efficient to me.

These ideas seem at odds to me. Without more information, I can only assume that by "not very efficient" you mean that the byte size of the presumably not-tree-shaken ES module is larger than the UMD module. If that's the case, why not just import Leaflet into your bundle and tree-shake away all of the parts that you don't use during build, resulting in even fewer bytes than the UMD?

Ignoring that for now, and responding purely to your stated criteria, below I will provide a self-contained, reproducible example demonstrating how you can use a CDN-hosted UMD module that has a corresponding `@types` package in a TypeScript ES module without augmenting the definition of `globalThis.window` in the compiler and without bundling.

> Note that some of what I show will be purely ceremonial, but the technique will allow for you to later swap out the shim module URL in the import map with a CDN ES module URL if/when you find one that suits you.

### Download the files in this example

> I'm going to provide a complete reproducible example here, including all the content of each file in a code block. If you want to use this example to reproduce it and don't want to copy + paste every individual code block into a new file with a matching name on your device, then you can copy + paste the following script and run it in your browser console to download the repo as a zip archive file:

```js
function download (data, fileName, mediaType) {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  const blob = new Blob([data], mediaType ? {type: mediaType} : undefined);
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.href = url;
  a.download = fileName;
  a.click();
  a.remove();
  // URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

download(
  new Uint8Array([80,75,3,4,20,0,0,0,8,0,173,178,247,84,63,79,13,255,254,0,0,0,4,24,0,0,9,0,28,0,46,68,83,95,83,116,111,114,101,85,84,9,0,3,182,186,220,98,78,194,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,237,152,49,78,196,48,16,69,255,132,72,88,162,113,73,233,43,236,13,204,42,112,129,109,232,64,75,34,40,178,202,22,32,218,92,135,123,112,27,46,65,140,255,66,68,130,4,5,218,21,252,39,89,47,146,199,246,164,177,61,6,96,203,135,122,1,120,0,14,217,150,62,102,112,108,19,10,186,76,131,223,230,104,112,143,166,189,93,172,110,186,249,185,14,142,148,251,49,174,80,15,185,183,227,252,55,219,81,212,167,136,77,87,85,235,182,91,15,61,238,165,121,186,124,188,120,62,155,139,170,191,17,181,189,155,172,38,132,16,66,252,38,150,229,78,246,155,134,16,226,0,73,251,67,160,35,221,103,27,251,11,186,28,141,241,116,160,35,221,103,27,227,10,186,164,29,237,233,64,71,186,207,230,166,101,44,62,140,43,239,138,23,243,116,160,227,143,126,89,136,127,195,81,150,79,231,255,249,215,245,191,16,226,15,99,101,181,170,150,120,47,8,38,164,179,54,12,237,122,55,0,60,205,49,189,4,20,249,177,240,20,31,253,129,142,116,159,173,139,128,16,251,226,21,80,75,3,4,10,0,0,0,0,0,135,182,247,84,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,0,28,0,46,109,101,116,97,95,105,103,110,111,114,101,95,116,104,105,115,47,85,84,9,0,3,237,193,220,98,62,194,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,80,75,3,4,20,0,0,0,8,0,210,178,247,84,4,129,138,94,194,1,0,0,133,3,0,0,50,0,28,0,46,109,101,116,97,95,105,103,110,111,114,101,95,116,104,105,115,47,99,114,101,97,116,101,45,105,110,108,105,110,101,45,97,114,99,104,105,118,101,45,115,99,114,105,112,116,46,109,106,115,85,84,9,0,3,252,186,220,98,252,186,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,117,146,77,139,219,48,16,134,239,254,21,115,88,176,93,130,12,61,149,132,165,236,210,221,195,210,238,150,182,123,10,129,40,210,56,81,99,75,70,146,29,82,227,255,222,81,28,39,74,161,167,120,70,207,188,239,124,68,213,141,177,30,62,0,119,208,112,191,131,210,154,26,82,109,36,206,67,156,46,18,53,34,189,217,7,136,59,135,214,15,49,55,166,10,231,173,18,62,42,176,200,229,179,170,240,6,46,93,209,80,164,28,58,66,19,97,180,243,176,44,9,251,78,118,43,184,7,122,22,232,28,227,118,219,49,87,41,129,217,199,124,145,140,46,217,68,206,32,125,176,98,167,58,132,144,26,155,167,146,182,70,237,65,27,31,116,58,37,81,166,249,197,231,143,106,190,112,207,31,219,146,124,248,129,43,15,83,147,23,97,162,111,224,23,103,52,209,107,141,7,120,87,218,127,122,176,150,31,179,187,254,229,231,219,43,11,67,235,173,42,143,217,146,49,118,213,95,229,67,190,142,148,130,197,43,175,241,172,246,79,109,104,158,109,184,67,77,200,181,147,184,149,111,40,21,255,117,108,254,163,144,242,166,161,85,113,175,140,46,8,143,134,118,194,170,198,135,17,202,86,139,0,128,52,7,93,25,46,33,147,212,238,236,180,193,208,221,12,234,201,38,135,62,1,24,21,56,21,75,35,78,171,101,130,54,230,241,169,194,16,145,111,112,154,192,77,101,54,196,134,85,61,210,103,182,12,242,171,72,21,62,67,239,233,119,126,77,13,48,135,86,75,44,149,70,25,105,181,182,34,169,247,31,95,207,142,111,155,223,40,60,197,89,112,57,129,156,237,44,134,83,18,59,198,151,193,238,47,51,141,15,130,150,179,207,206,85,22,107,211,225,24,21,197,201,195,98,103,246,145,7,41,210,243,144,36,147,98,70,236,93,31,253,39,134,217,148,137,111,123,205,222,28,140,210,249,98,125,62,137,169,144,85,102,155,141,135,33,155,191,80,75,3,4,20,0,0,0,8,0,128,182,247,84,134,228,110,93,72,0,0,0,86,0,0,0,28,0,28,0,46,109,101,116,97,95,105,103,110,111,114,101,95,116,104,105,115,47,82,69,65,68,77,69,46,116,120,116,85,84,9,0,3,224,193,220,98,224,193,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,29,202,209,9,128,48,12,5,192,127,167,120,67,185,64,104,35,13,132,68,146,104,209,233,45,194,125,222,62,36,177,184,233,131,43,185,163,28,45,152,138,81,131,33,166,98,140,87,78,80,180,33,55,227,16,101,116,159,166,78,29,217,66,206,90,239,239,100,57,57,182,15,80,75,3,4,20,0,0,0,8,0,39,179,247,84,89,60,189,69,88,0,0,0,119,0,0,0,21,0,28,0,46,109,101,116,97,95,105,103,110,111,114,101,95,116,104,105,115,47,114,117,110,85,84,9,0,3,153,187,220,98,153,187,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,101,204,59,14,128,32,12,0,208,221,83,112,129,22,127,137,241,52,132,96,35,53,242,177,16,7,78,175,179,174,111,120,141,179,130,75,84,73,176,76,253,58,244,243,136,237,53,236,98,218,72,161,198,64,213,26,222,99,18,50,213,115,209,78,200,86,2,142,39,71,2,43,206,243,77,80,156,112,174,24,142,242,189,58,9,63,122,0,80,75,3,4,10,0,0,0,0,0,198,181,247,84,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,28,0,112,117,98,108,105,99,47,85,84,9,0,3,131,192,220,98,140,192,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,80,75,3,4,20,0,0,0,8,0,138,181,247,84,83,75,4,148,85,1,0,0,77,2,0,0,17,0,28,0,112,117,98,108,105,99,47,105,110,100,101,120,46,104,116,109,108,85,84,9,0,3,19,192,220,98,19,192,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,125,82,77,79,195,48,12,189,239,87,152,156,23,186,1,18,48,181,61,1,55,196,97,112,70,33,117,137,33,31,85,226,110,154,16,255,157,38,29,236,198,37,78,252,158,253,252,145,250,172,11,154,15,3,130,97,103,219,69,157,13,88,229,223,27,129,94,180,139,201,131,170,107,23,0,181,67,86,160,141,138,9,185,17,35,247,242,70,64,117,130,188,114,216,136,29,225,126,8,145,5,232,224,25,253,68,221,83,199,166,233,112,71,26,101,121,44,129,60,49,41,43,147,86,22,155,117,73,148,51,49,177,197,118,203,74,127,194,211,14,99,111,195,30,174,47,87,183,235,213,213,69,93,205,112,97,158,73,9,15,20,19,47,161,195,158,60,130,242,64,46,107,131,83,3,244,33,2,27,4,97,81,245,22,167,130,92,232,70,139,144,6,212,212,19,198,41,203,222,144,54,48,4,242,156,128,67,9,120,121,188,147,28,228,253,246,17,146,33,119,12,219,128,148,165,215,164,35,13,12,121,104,141,152,245,38,57,145,49,128,175,114,2,28,129,36,54,127,46,56,85,178,1,81,29,239,175,163,235,94,179,204,249,71,18,71,230,119,177,223,249,200,130,213,172,120,234,250,217,160,95,254,182,154,43,158,166,28,15,165,137,127,139,157,49,1,41,234,70,84,78,145,207,162,237,73,160,174,230,101,47,234,183,208,29,74,2,179,110,183,136,121,151,41,76,179,11,35,15,35,79,188,117,102,207,172,28,86,62,207,15,80,75,3,4,20,0,0,0,8,0,72,187,247,84,206,95,24,128,103,0,0,0,156,0,0,0,14,0,28,0,112,117,98,108,105,99,47,109,97,105,110,46,106,115,85,84,9,0,3,232,201,220,98,234,201,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,203,204,45,200,47,42,81,240,81,72,43,202,207,85,80,207,73,77,76,203,73,45,81,183,230,74,206,207,43,46,81,72,84,176,85,240,209,203,73,44,241,201,75,215,48,53,208,51,213,81,48,6,146,154,48,249,36,20,121,67,12,249,148,204,226,146,196,188,228,84,160,178,68,61,24,39,36,95,35,9,170,34,63,39,85,47,39,63,93,163,90,33,81,71,33,73,7,161,190,22,168,0,0,80,75,3,4,20,0,0,0,8,0,72,187,247,84,107,96,82,240,103,0,0,0,114,0,0,0,26,0,28,0,112,117,98,108,105,99,47,108,101,97,102,108,101,116,95,117,109,100,95,115,104,105,109,46,106,115,85,84,9,0,3,232,201,220,98,234,201,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,53,204,49,10,195,48,12,0,192,221,175,208,150,77,106,183,82,211,31,228,19,174,45,83,27,197,10,145,66,2,165,127,47,20,58,222,114,109,89,117,115,152,94,238,171,221,137,114,25,221,48,139,238,165,74,218,24,179,46,148,122,58,73,218,211,72,56,85,97,167,43,222,240,242,23,118,155,98,200,58,204,225,13,51,124,224,1,71,27,69,143,24,248,252,253,133,107,218,197,97,142,225,11,80,75,3,4,20,0,0,0,8,0,197,174,247,84,125,16,35,51,209,0,0,0,89,1,0,0,12,0,28,0,112,97,99,107,97,103,101,46,106,115,111,110,85,84,9,0,3,81,180,220,98,180,186,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,85,79,187,170,2,49,16,237,247,43,66,234,187,113,162,139,47,16,44,110,115,11,59,107,33,102,71,12,100,147,176,137,11,23,241,223,77,38,136,10,83,204,156,71,206,201,189,97,140,59,53,32,223,50,30,125,187,90,192,70,66,55,231,63,133,152,112,140,198,187,194,129,144,2,42,154,254,3,201,7,223,223,44,86,44,234,209,132,20,51,124,207,103,6,180,31,130,177,164,75,81,147,168,200,112,156,106,84,82,201,104,214,182,193,143,105,183,6,128,188,107,165,175,184,187,40,27,145,133,219,217,26,205,179,237,65,1,249,64,23,201,123,248,59,214,208,30,167,95,12,232,122,116,218,224,71,248,190,84,140,51,139,234,98,49,21,207,73,138,149,144,242,213,195,249,30,219,218,129,88,248,98,201,77,31,34,178,203,100,247,110,50,121,155,212,59,171,60,85,100,114,41,242,0,233,154,71,243,4,80,75,3,4,20,0,0,0,8,0,239,181,247,84,19,66,213,63,231,1,0,0,179,3,0,0,13,0,28,0,116,115,99,111,110,102,105,103,46,106,115,111,110,85,84,9,0,3,210,192,220,98,212,192,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,141,83,193,110,219,48,12,189,231,43,8,239,178,21,107,124,207,105,93,183,67,128,21,43,154,116,151,162,24,100,137,137,181,72,162,65,209,113,140,162,255,62,201,142,155,164,167,2,190,232,233,241,241,209,143,122,153,1,20,154,124,99,29,242,239,70,44,133,88,44,224,37,193,0,101,9,43,97,171,5,104,188,129,207,235,218,70,72,223,122,181,0,233,27,132,168,54,40,125,134,172,111,136,69,5,249,50,20,23,120,80,90,70,73,229,238,153,26,100,233,215,169,38,55,16,110,241,235,200,179,145,156,18,52,119,100,90,247,254,50,208,99,208,53,234,29,154,101,48,120,64,115,163,53,198,119,172,56,184,188,196,218,136,143,97,23,168,11,203,112,171,68,215,127,20,91,85,157,119,152,134,252,185,186,59,90,142,163,137,101,16,76,134,47,5,253,112,149,176,68,11,120,144,226,2,127,192,52,70,155,135,205,140,64,6,143,156,145,228,108,149,240,167,225,0,39,133,220,253,87,26,62,74,50,1,177,15,162,14,176,65,37,45,99,156,200,134,252,200,252,206,212,69,100,224,54,136,245,8,24,246,150,41,248,32,103,212,185,77,222,243,156,197,7,74,158,39,127,162,120,139,114,62,92,174,190,49,255,218,100,77,114,232,66,208,83,203,80,29,21,199,10,8,136,38,30,69,168,149,31,150,179,72,211,86,206,234,81,36,65,168,133,184,135,13,147,135,174,182,186,78,146,105,117,146,83,232,172,115,80,165,3,242,30,205,91,36,247,74,106,240,170,105,108,216,78,216,3,110,22,80,139,52,113,81,150,93,215,205,243,2,70,205,182,17,167,194,118,78,188,45,13,233,88,214,42,152,138,104,87,142,209,92,243,91,54,243,90,188,251,212,36,241,235,115,241,162,82,105,91,216,101,235,243,41,215,204,58,189,133,156,33,170,141,27,126,210,211,16,240,223,81,62,150,223,6,35,229,116,255,60,20,188,158,246,107,122,4,105,72,145,212,115,76,182,96,244,180,199,91,242,30,131,76,91,57,27,42,243,179,8,218,181,6,135,110,145,117,121,117,85,94,37,233,215,217,127,80,75,3,4,10,0,0,0,0,0,236,157,247,84,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,28,0,115,114,99,47,85,84,9,0,3,156,150,220,98,45,152,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,80,75,3,4,20,0,0,0,8,0,50,187,247,84,183,28,133,184,171,1,0,0,246,2,0,0,11,0,28,0,115,114,99,47,109,97,105,110,46,116,115,85,84,9,0,3,191,201,220,98,192,201,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,125,82,77,111,219,48,12,189,235,87,16,190,196,14,50,123,217,146,174,117,208,219,122,24,144,1,195,154,158,91,197,166,109,161,250,200,100,186,73,17,228,191,143,114,236,0,93,128,233,32,144,143,212,227,211,147,178,169,16,241,111,172,208,163,45,16,10,103,12,90,106,65,89,136,52,202,74,35,61,119,166,124,110,27,101,82,106,35,168,156,231,46,75,120,160,68,60,28,164,217,105,4,87,129,117,246,211,222,249,87,101,107,176,210,96,9,202,236,156,167,92,136,115,0,71,82,26,215,242,29,253,9,42,239,12,76,134,1,147,149,16,63,8,246,174,211,37,80,227,221,158,119,228,73,90,187,125,224,243,157,37,101,16,240,80,224,142,148,179,185,136,158,108,33,187,186,33,120,124,183,36,15,15,222,59,159,195,134,207,121,252,211,97,75,172,192,184,178,99,117,151,57,80,58,108,89,41,193,206,187,55,85,162,144,150,73,123,117,103,205,147,139,198,73,36,196,166,81,45,16,22,141,85,76,217,19,43,207,12,231,11,5,101,65,39,251,197,40,60,253,252,62,14,116,22,100,79,8,49,190,161,5,85,113,163,36,209,67,76,25,149,88,201,78,83,148,176,59,211,76,136,44,131,199,80,147,45,188,140,110,13,61,1,91,255,107,216,75,62,154,186,190,182,146,95,167,229,99,112,15,235,84,75,90,219,58,94,126,78,151,51,248,202,123,178,26,234,219,15,245,249,85,189,84,45,201,240,37,238,65,166,99,178,113,241,54,25,70,56,141,169,118,117,124,148,51,216,206,46,253,167,100,5,217,20,126,121,21,190,209,135,119,228,203,30,5,64,36,163,28,66,192,33,207,231,164,151,55,0,182,102,32,40,225,252,20,192,104,123,213,62,255,95,251,40,132,241,57,175,187,69,122,247,229,230,102,177,88,46,111,191,45,196,169,55,252,47,80,75,3,4,20,0,0,0,8,0,242,180,247,84,94,247,21,86,106,2,0,0,125,4,0,0,23,0,28,0,115,114,99,47,108,101,97,102,108,101,116,95,117,109,100,95,115,104,105,109,46,116,115,85,84,9,0,3,247,190,220,98,248,190,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,117,83,75,110,219,48,16,221,243,20,3,111,236,4,174,212,238,138,4,93,37,5,186,80,178,104,154,189,41,114,100,209,161,72,133,31,203,66,16,160,135,232,9,123,146,14,37,202,73,81,20,208,98,40,206,231,125,56,101,9,55,14,121,64,15,28,122,103,79,35,4,11,161,69,120,188,187,133,10,121,163,49,128,173,15,40,2,236,6,101,164,29,138,106,7,60,229,135,177,199,15,158,55,8,95,31,238,0,79,189,117,129,177,242,146,177,31,173,242,160,45,151,30,54,220,72,186,67,17,105,200,197,63,173,189,112,170,15,211,239,70,57,79,145,234,144,142,60,176,144,154,116,86,70,141,64,145,234,82,127,148,160,76,134,152,239,246,142,247,237,22,134,86,137,150,128,121,181,55,158,253,135,2,85,190,177,40,96,194,73,159,23,182,71,232,173,214,49,40,107,182,144,64,43,207,172,65,176,205,52,140,208,152,189,159,144,17,221,60,155,84,56,90,37,183,80,199,144,250,24,20,232,61,119,35,180,232,16,106,20,60,122,100,163,141,73,30,71,119,132,95,42,74,9,202,55,92,164,97,192,103,250,252,200,149,230,53,17,90,48,159,199,128,237,83,166,103,148,138,39,229,3,65,129,155,219,123,120,252,94,249,34,203,157,221,67,209,26,245,28,17,86,131,117,79,126,5,3,106,253,23,156,165,63,163,34,110,22,101,102,251,74,195,59,223,115,129,89,1,144,86,196,14,77,210,157,180,171,17,98,162,48,89,51,240,177,128,111,118,192,35,186,45,51,54,204,190,193,239,159,191,160,177,14,44,177,114,103,161,102,123,8,228,81,73,178,46,234,160,122,98,54,143,205,186,114,135,140,220,69,35,207,227,222,185,46,21,149,70,174,245,8,245,8,4,20,167,81,19,150,55,218,131,141,90,154,117,160,98,198,97,111,173,164,135,21,206,220,41,116,248,28,21,121,49,169,78,212,40,158,158,74,214,122,158,219,113,249,206,18,150,108,2,79,178,83,194,38,141,150,23,25,122,1,155,251,51,245,212,81,98,195,137,93,190,78,26,30,34,189,107,62,33,150,203,154,196,212,108,202,159,136,172,114,213,234,130,236,188,44,25,155,121,195,186,13,161,247,87,101,41,164,57,248,66,104,27,101,163,73,167,66,216,174,228,7,126,42,181,170,125,169,103,75,203,79,197,231,226,227,114,42,14,126,125,125,110,149,182,21,46,211,230,46,239,171,113,182,131,117,78,78,153,130,222,88,128,151,234,21,190,192,188,37,41,61,154,39,99,7,147,194,23,168,174,166,70,180,20,75,151,87,42,44,75,120,72,52,40,101,151,121,191,84,233,148,105,189,238,174,88,254,191,200,83,93,179,63,80,75,1,2,30,3,20,0,0,0,8,0,173,178,247,84,63,79,13,255,254,0,0,0,4,24,0,0,9,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,164,129,0,0,0,0,46,68,83,95,83,116,111,114,101,85,84,5,0,3,182,186,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,80,75,1,2,30,3,10,0,0,0,0,0,135,182,247,84,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,237,65,65,1,0,0,46,109,101,116,97,95,105,103,110,111,114,101,95,116,104,105,115,47,85,84,5,0,3,237,193,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,80,75,1,2,30,3,20,0,0,0,8,0,210,178,247,84,4,129,138,94,194,1,0,0,133,3,0,0,50,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,164,129,141,1,0,0,46,109,101,116,97,95,105,103,110,111,114,101,95,116,104,105,115,47,99,114,101,97,116,101,45,105,110,108,105,110,101,45,97,114,99,104,105,118,101,45,115,99,114,105,112,116,46,109,106,115,85,84,5,0,3,252,186,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,80,75,1,2,30,3,20,0,0,0,8,0,128,182,247,84,134,228,110,93,72,0,0,0,86,0,0,0,28,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,164,129,187,3,0,0,46,109,101,116,97,95,105,103,110,111,114,101,95,116,104,105,115,47,82,69,65,68,77,69,46,116,120,116,85,84,5,0,3,224,193,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,80,75,1,2,30,3,20,0,0,0,8,0,39,179,247,84,89,60,189,69,88,0,0,0,119,0,0,0,21,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,228,129,89,4,0,0,46,109,101,116,97,95,105,103,110,111,114,101,95,116,104,105,115,47,114,117,110,85,84,5,0,3,153,187,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,80,75,1,2,30,3,10,0,0,0,0,0,198,181,247,84,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,237,65,0,5,0,0,112,117,98,108,105,99,47,85,84,5,0,3,131,192,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,80,75,1,2,30,3,20,0,0,0,8,0,138,181,247,84,83,75,4,148,85,1,0,0,77,2,0,0,17,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,164,129,65,5,0,0,112,117,98,108,105,99,47,105,110,100,101,120,46,104,116,109,108,85,84,5,0,3,19,192,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,80,75,1,2,30,3,20,0,0,0,8,0,72,187,247,84,206,95,24,128,103,0,0,0,156,0,0,0,14,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,164,129,225,6,0,0,112,117,98,108,105,99,47,109,97,105,110,46,106,115,85,84,5,0,3,232,201,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,80,75,1,2,30,3,20,0,0,0,8,0,72,187,247,84,107,96,82,240,103,0,0,0,114,0,0,0,26,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,164,129,144,7,0,0,112,117,98,108,105,99,47,108,101,97,102,108,101,116,95,117,109,100,95,115,104,105,109,46,106,115,85,84,5,0,3,232,201,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,80,75,1,2,30,3,20,0,0,0,8,0,197,174,247,84,125,16,35,51,209,0,0,0,89,1,0,0,12,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,164,129,75,8,0,0,112,97,99,107,97,103,101,46,106,115,111,110,85,84,5,0,3,81,180,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,80,75,1,2,30,3,20,0,0,0,8,0,239,181,247,84,19,66,213,63,231,1,0,0,179,3,0,0,13,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,164,129,98,9,0,0,116,115,99,111,110,102,105,103,46,106,115,111,110,85,84,5,0,3,210,192,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,80,75,1,2,30,3,10,0,0,0,0,0,236,157,247,84,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,237,65,144,11,0,0,115,114,99,47,85,84,5,0,3,156,150,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,80,75,1,2,30,3,20,0,0,0,8,0,50,187,247,84,183,28,133,184,171,1,0,0,246,2,0,0,11,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,164,129,206,11,0,0,115,114,99,47,109,97,105,110,46,116,115,85,84,5,0,3,191,201,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,80,75,1,2,30,3,20,0,0,0,8,0,242,180,247,84,94,247,21,86,106,2,0,0,125,4,0,0,23,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,164,129,190,13,0,0,115,114,99,47,108,101,97,102,108,101,116,95,117,109,100,95,115,104,105,109,46,116,115,85,84,5,0,3,247,190,220,98,117,120,11,0,1,4,245,1,0,0,4,20,0,0,0,80,75,5,6,0,0,0,0,14,0,14,0,209,4,0,0,121,16,0,0,0,0]),
  "so-73091042.zip",
  "application/zip",
);
```

### Example

This example will be served using a static file server from the `./public` directory, and the entrypoint html file is here:

`./public/index.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <title>Stack Overflow 73091042</title>

  <!-- First, define an import map for the "leaflet" module specifier
  which points to the UMD-to-ESM shim module: -->
  <script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "leaflet": "/leaflet_umd_shim.js"
      }
    }    
  </script>

  <!-- Then, import the entrypoint module: -->
  <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>See console output</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Nothing special there except maybe the import map if you aren't familiar: [WICG/import-maps: How to control the behavior of JavaScript imports](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps)

Next, there are two TypeScript source files in the `./src` directory which are transpiled to JavaScript and copied into the `./public` directory during compilation.

The first is a shim:

`./src/leaflet_umd_shim.ts`:

```ts
// Creates a proxy to the UMD Leaflet object `window.L` as a type-safe ESM export

/*

This loads (and executes) the UMD Leaflet script the first time that
this module is imported into the module graph, which assigns
the UMD Leaflet object to `window.L`. This is scope pollution, and is
one of the things that ES modules avoid, but is necessary here because
you expressed dissatisfaction at the available Leaflet ES module options
at existing CDN URLs.

This proxy technique "works" well here because Leaflet
is an object export/namspace and is documented to be used this way. However,
note that — for other modules which provide multiple exports that are
intended to be imported individually by name — this technique wouldn't be
a good fit because it requires the entire UMD module to be made available
on a single (named) export. (Note that the default export is just a named export
using the name "default").

*/

import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.8.0/leaflet.js';

import type * as Leaflet from 'leaflet';

const {L} = window as unknown as { L: typeof Leaflet };

// Same as `export {L as default}`:
export default L;
```

The `"leaflet"` import specifier in the import map is bound to the location of the JavaScript module produced by this file during compilation.

That specifier is used in the entrypoint module:

`./src/main.ts`:

```ts
/*

(Reference comments in "leaflet_umd_shim.ts" for context)
Example of non-working named import:

import {tileLayer} from 'leaflet';

It would throw the following runtime exception:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'leaflet' does not provide
an export named 'tileLayer'"

This technique requires importing the entire UMD module on a name (even if that
name is "default"):

*/

// Same as `import {default as L} from 'leaflet'`:
import L from 'leaflet';

const a = L.latLng(50.5, 30.5);
const b = L.latLng(51.5, 30.5);
const distance = a.distanceTo(b);

console.log({a, b, distance}); /* Prints the following:

{
  "a": {
    "lat": 50.5,
    "lng": 30.5
  },
  "b": {
    "lat": 51.5,
    "lng": 30.5
  },
  "distance": 111194.92664455874
}

*/
```

When you serve this site on a local http server and access the HTML file, the main module will execute and print that information to the console using those methods from Leaflet to create the data that is logged, proving that this technique works.

Here's my TSConfig:

`./tsconfig.json`:

```jsonc
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Strict options (This is TS: type safety is important)
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "strict": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,

    // ESM
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext",

    "lib": [
      "esnext", // Latest ES syntax features
      "dom", // Browser runtime environmnt
      "dom.iterable" // Browser runtime environmnt
    ],

    "target": "esnext", // Adjust this to your browser target needs

    "outDir": "public", // Directory from which the site will be served

    // Path mapping
    // Ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "leaflet": ["node_modules/@types/leaflet"]
    },

    // Optional settings
    "removeComments": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

And, lastly, here's the npm package file:

`./package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "so-73091042",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc",
    "serve": "static --port=8000 --cache=false public"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.7.11",
    "node-static": "^0.7.11",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "volta": {
    "node": "16.16.0"
  }
}
```

You can ignore the `volta` property: it just shows that I was using [Volta](https://volta.sh/) and the version of Node that I had installed when creating this repository example.

> The [`node-static`](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static) dependency is the package recommended by the official Node.js website for serving static files in the article [How to serve static files | Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/).

First use `npm install` to install the dependencies:

```
% npm install

added 9 packages, and audited 10 packages in 4s
```

Then — to compile the TS files and emit them — use `npm run compile`:

```
% npm run compile

> so-73091042@0.1.0 compile
> tsc
```

There should now be two new files in the `./public` directory after compilation:

`./public/leaflet_umd_shim.js`:

```js
import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.8.0/leaflet.js';
const { L } = window;
export default L;
```

`./public/main.js`:

```js
import L from 'leaflet';
const a = L.latLng(50.5, 30.5);
const b = L.latLng(51.5, 30.5);
const distance = a.distanceTo(b);
console.log({ a, b, distance });
```

Now everything is ready to be served by the static file server, so use the command `npm run serve`:

```
% npm run serve 

> so-73091042@0.1.0 serve
> static --port=8000 --cache=false public

serving "public" at http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

If you navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8000 in your browser (this is the same as http://localhost:8000), you'll see the index page with the text "See console output", and if you look at your browser's JS console, you'll see a representation of the object data that was logged to the console in the `main.js` module.

> When you're ready to stop the server, just use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> in your terminal

And that's it!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such a exhaustive answer!

Comment: About the tree-shaking, the reason I want to keep the option to not use a bundler is that the project I'm working on will mainly be working with _warm cashes_ and [unbundled code might have better performance in this case](https://v8.dev/features/modules#bundle-tradeoffs). Not using complex build tools also should keep development simpler and more future-proof.
First visit load times should still be as fast as possible though. So that's why I don't want to download all source files from leaflet.
I'm not very experienced, so I'm curious to know if I'm missing something in my reasoning here.

Comment: @AronSchöffer Using ES modules can allow you to [tree shake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Tree_shaking) (omit unused code) when eliding your output. Bundling is a broad term and doesn't mean "one massive JS file" in many cases. [Code splitting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Code_splitting) allows you to import the parts of an external module that are relevant to your application, and then bundle just those parts together into one module so that it can be imported from by other bundles with separate concerns.

Comment: So, in your case, you could import the parts of Leaflet that you actually use and re-export just those parts from one bundled module. Then, in another bundled module which might have started as multiple TS source files (e.g. for code management concerns), you can import the relevant parts of Leaflet from the first bundle. Then — when just your application code bundle changes — the Leaflet bundle won't (unless you use more/less of its API, which would case that bundle to change). Make sense?

Comment: ah okay, I did think bundlers made "one massive JS file" :). It doesn't completely make sense to me however. I'll read up on it a bit more first and post a new question if it still doesn't make sense. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Fantastic answer! One follow-up question: is there a way to do the equivalent of `importmap` on the `tsc` side? Like, to allow writing `import L from 'leaflet';` in your TS code, but have that emit JS that contains `import L from '<URL>';` instead?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73091042/importing-leaflet-into-module-from-cdn-with-typescript-support/73095875?noredirect=1#comment134311484_73095875) @HighCommander4 No, [TS doesn't rewrite import specifiers](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50501).