# Using money library in typescript after downloading it locally

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've been trying to install a library for the first time in typescript and just can't get it to working. The library is [money](http://openexchangerates.github.io/money.js/#basic-install). I have downloaded it to the root of my project and I did as it asked and added

```
<script type="module" src="money.js"></script>
```

to my HTML header. Then I tried to use import in typescript

```
import fx from "money.js";
```

but I cannot get it to work. How do install this library?

EDIT: I got it to work, I had to declare it in the typescript file

```
declare var fx: any;
```

It is probably me being and dumb and barely knowing typescript, but tbf nowhere in the documentation it's reported

Comment: You need to install it using `npm install money` as is detailed in the following section of the documentation, https://openexchangerates.github.io/money.js/#nodeJS-npm.

Comment: The `type=module` attribute  added to the script tag is not part of the linked documentation and probably should be omitted. The script in fact adds the `fx` object referred to in  documentation as a property of the global `window` object in a browser. As a JS programmer, how to use it in TS is not something I can answer.

Comment: I installed using the npm command but it doesn't work still, and apparently fx isn't global since I can' reference without having an error

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73095875/438273) might help if you’re using a UMD script for “money.js”.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it from https://www.npmjs.com/package/money

```
npm install money
npm install -D @types/money
```

and then it'll work as

```
import fx from 'money'
```

Comment: why would they `npm install money` if they're already pulling it via script tag?